# Anybody else seen this Virtualbox error?

Tags: virtualbox, oracle

I boot to Virtualbox and get a totally black screen that's impossible to navigate.

Tried installing and reinstalling (from the Oracle Virtualbox website).

Anybody have any ideas how to fix this?

[image: Useless Virtualbox interface upon boot]

Window manager also look strange (I'm on Lubuntu 18.04)

[image]

Comment: Do you have a discrete graphics card? If so, have you installed drivers?

Comment: Yup, I have an Nvidia card. I'm actually using the Noveau / open-source drivers, because the last time I used Nvidia on Ubuntu 18 it caused problems (only one monitor recognized and at the wrong resolution).

Comment: It was the wrong driver version probably. Always install the recommended version and you should be fine. The problem you're seeing now is because the `nouveau` is inadequate. So either live with it or install the proper drivers.

Comment: That looks like a theme error.  Try a different theme on your system.

Comment: I'm using Lubuntu (with stock LXDE) but installed some GNOME packages recently. I'm wondering if that cold have caused the error. Installing the Nvidia drivers now and going to see whether that resolves things.

Comment: I've noticed that the file saving dialog has drastically changed appearance recently in a couple of other programs, so perhaps this is all related

Comment: I'm on the Nvidia drivers now and the issue unfortunately still persists.

Comment: You're running Android VM. Usually for that you need emulator like Genymotion. I've never been able to run an Android VM just via Virtual Box alone. But maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: The GTK Theme is what I meant by looking messed up.  If you go to your `Application Menu -> Preferences -> Customize Look and Feel` you should be able to choose a different theme there under Widget and see if that fixes your menu so you can see them again.  I experienced the closer  texts on the menus when I was using a Box theme from Lubuntu.  Chose a different one and things seem to go back to normal.

Comment: Yeah, I'm able to run the VM fine through Genymotion. I can still run my Windows 10 VM just fine, but it's obviously not ideal that the UI is basically non-functional.

Comment: I'm using the default Lubuntu theme.